# Issue while populating data from jquery success to modal

Tags: python, jquery, django

I have a function that uses an AJAX request to fetch data from a view and returns data in the form of a list that is in the model.

In my model the data is entered with a new line character, however in my jQuery output the `\n` character is ignored. Can anyone help?

Data in Model object:

```
ankit: Hi govind!
go358938: Hi Ankit, how are you  ?
```

Data passed as list to jquery:

```
{ 'list': 'ankit: Hi govind!\r\ngo358938: Hi Ankit, how are you  ?' }
```

Data visible in Modal :

```
ankit: Hi govind! go358938: Hi Ankit, how are you ?
```

```js
$('#chatbox').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') 
  $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'fetcher' %}",
    data: {
      'search': recipient
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      list = data.list;
      $('#chatbox').find('.modal-body').html(list);
    }
  });
});
```

Views.py

```
def fetcher(request):
if request.is_ajax():
  name = User.objects.get(username=request.GET.get('search', None))
  b = ChatMessage.objects.get(user2 = name)
  print(b.message)
  data = {
    'list': b.message,
  }
  return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: html doesn't know `\n`. You'll need to transform these to something else like `<br/>`.

Comment: okay ! so using <PRE> solves the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, what do you mean with "jquery"-output?

Your output in the HTML as Website? Well, "\n" is not considered there as "break" but `<br/>`.

Your html file technically looks like this:

```
<div>\n
  <p>Whatever</p>\n
  <p>Something different</p>\n
</div>
```

You don't want to count every `\n` as `<br/>`.

You have two options:

Print your results inside a html element which supports `\n` (e.g. `<pre>, <code> and <textarea>` do) or replace your `\n` with a `<br/>`).

**Solution 1:**

```
<textarea class="modal-body-content">
This is a new line\nhere
</textarea>

$('#chatbox').find('.modal-body-content').html(list);
```

**Solution 2:**

```
$('#chatbox').find('.modal-body').html(list.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
```

Comment: thanks, using PRE solves it. Sorry, i am new to all this. Thanks for understanding.